# Server - Windows 2K8/IIS7/ColdFusion throwing intermittent 403 errors

Tags: iis, coldfusion, windows-server-2008

We've just set up a new dedicated server at hostgator, running Windows 2008 Server, IIS7 and ColdFusion 8 ENT.

On browsing the homepage, sometimes the site works, sometimes, part of the site runs and I can see a 403 error in Firebug. At other times, I only get an IIS error page saying:

**"403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied."**

The site is http://www.asia-buy.com. It might run first time, but if you refresh it a few times, you'll probably encounter the problem.

There is a lot of ajax and JSON stuff going on under the hood and I'm wondering if that has any bearing on the problem.

Would appreciate advice from anyone who may have solved a similar issue in the past.

Answer (score 6):

Resolved: Hostgator says this is actually a security setting in IIS to attempt to prevent DDOS attacks on the website. A a developer, I use CTRL-F5 a lot. A normal user would not.

Full error:
HTTP Error 403.502 - Forbidden
The IP address from which you are browsing is not permitted to access the requested Web site because it has made too many requests over short period of time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open IIS Manager.
2. Go to your website.
3. Go to  Features/IP Address and Domain Restrictions/Dynamic IP Restriction Settings
4. Uncheck the boxes, or change the values, as needed

[image]